# Meaning of " The huts gaped black"

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> And the village was deserted, the huts gaped black, rotting, all askew within the fallen enclosures. A calamity had come to it, sure enough

Does *the huts gaped black* mean that the huts were wide open with no light inside?

Comment: Possibly. If you could supply a little more of this passage for context, it would help others figure out the meaning.

Comment: Sure, I've added it. Thanks

Comment: It's from the "Heart of Darkness" by Joseph Conrad. Yes, "the huts gaped black" means what you thought.

Comment: And "black" might also imply from decay, as well as from lack of lighting. Both might be intended. Also, the connotation of "black" is associated with sadness e.g. "black despair." Rather impressive use of language by Conrad, where English was the *third* conversational language he learned!

Comment: Impressive indeed!!